# How to do a 'gray box' or inline panel?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I'm working on a site using Twitter Bootstrap, and want to put some content in a gray box or panel.

I mean much like the ['Basic block' example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#code-block) from bootstrap's own docs. Small screenshot cutout to display what I mean:

[image]

Except it's supposed to contain normal HTML content, no code or <pre> stuff or anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `well` for this. See [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#wells).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="well well-sm">Well well well</div>
```